# Tweaks for ChrUbuntu 12.04 on Acer C7?

Tags: 12.04, acer, chromebook, chrubuntu

I recently purchased an Acer C7 and installed ChrUbuntu 12.04 on it successfully.  The laptop so far is fitting my needs (something cheap to carry to labs/read PDFs and email with) but it's pretty sluggish at times.  Are there any tweaks to speed it up a bit, allow 720p to be more playable, etc?  I've read Lubuntu and Xubuntu are built for lower end hardware, is it possible to install that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be "Mr. Obvious" but I say this from direct experience.

RAM

My wife and I both have these units running 12.04. I left hers at default memory levels, but I upgraded my unit to 8GB of RAM. You can go as high as 16GB of RAM!

The difference is noticeable, especially when running video, streaming, etc.

You'll need a small Phillips-head screwdriver and the appropriate RAM sticks. Here is a video tutorial from someone who is running Chrubuntu on their Acer C7.

http://youtu.be/EbkRHuzstWM